# Unable to strip the following libraries in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

All of my previously built projects fail to build, I cannot run any of my previously built projects which were working fine before, I updated both android studio and node.js, yet it didn't work

When I create a new project I get the below error

```
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbetter.so, libc++_shared.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_futures.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes-executor-common-debug.so, libhermes-executor-common-release.so, libhermes-executor-debug.so, libhermes-executor-release.so, libhermes-inspector.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsc.so, libjscexecutor.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactconfig.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactnativeutilsjni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_modal.so, librrc_picker.so, librrc_progressbar.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_slider.so, librrc_switch.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textinput.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'pixel(AVD) - 11' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.
```

[image: app:stripDebugDebugSymbols]

Comment: Failing to strip a shared object isn't the same as failing to build. Based on your screenshot, the build was successful as it literally says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL".

Comment: @Ouroborus that's when I create a new project, but none of my previously built projects are working, they were working properly before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open SDK manager in Android Studio and install **Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).